# Passing objects to IIFE

Tags: javascript, closures

I am generating a function and pushing it to the array using IIFE as follows:

```
var arr = [];
  var k;
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    k = {"val" : i};
    arr.push(
      (function(j) {
        return function() {
          console.log(j)
        };
      }(k))
    )
  }
console.log(arr[0](), arr[1](), arr[2]());
```

Output:

```
Object {val: 0}
Object {val: 1}
Object {val: 2}
```

However I am passing `k` which is an object generated using `i` . Since objects are passed by reference , I was expecting it to log objects with values `2,2,2` but instead I got `0,1,2`. Isn't this the usual behaviour when primitive type which are passed by value ? , Why is the same thing happening even when I use pass by reference (objects) ?

Comment: The reference that's maintained is to the object that `k` happened to hold, not to "whatever the current value of `k` is"

Comment: @zzzzBov , I thought the functions that are being returned saved the variable environment of the IIFE which is `j` ? and since `k` is passed by reference , I thought changing `k` changed `j`? , can you please explain? Thank you :)

Comment: You're misusing the term of art "pass by reference." JavaScript has no pass-by-reference, at all, anywhere. It uses object references, yes, which is an entirely different thing than pass-by-reference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , yeah I meant the object references, Thank you :)

Comment: The key point I was making above is that **everything** is pass-by-value in JavaScript. "Pass-by-reference" is a *term of art* with a specific meaning (passing a reference to a *variable* into a function). JavaScript never does that. But yes, the *value* passed in relation to objects is an object reference. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get 0, 1, 2 instead of 3, 3, 3 because the **value** of `k` is passed into the function. The **value** of `k` is an object reference. JavaScript doesn't have any form of pass-by-reference, so what the function receives is not a reference to the `k` *variable*, it's a copy of the object reference that's in `k` as of when you call the function. On the next pass, you create a new object and put that in the `k` variable, but that has no effect at all on the value of the `j` variable that the innermost function closes over.

Think of an object reference as though it were an index into a big array (memory) that tells the JavaScript engine where the object is. `k` contains that reference (the number), not the actual object. When you copy the reference into a second variable (or pass it into a function), you have two copies of the *reference* to the object, but just one object.

Let's simplify, and throw some ASCII-art at it: :-)

```
var k = {val: 0};
```

After those lines of code, here's what we have in memory (leaving out some unnecessary details):

```
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
k:REF#123−−−−−−−−−−−>| Object@REF#123 |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     | val: 0         |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`k` contains the reference (I've arbitrarily called it `REF#123` but we never actually see the raw values); the object is elsewhere.

Now if we do this:

```
var j = k;
```

...we have this:

```
k:REF#123−−−−−−+
               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
               +−−−−>| Object@REF#123 |
               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
j:REF#123−−−−−−+     | val: 0         |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how `k` and `j` have the same value, REF#123. So regardless of which variable you look at, the JavaScript engine will go to that object in memory.

Now suppose we do this:

```
k = {val: 1};
```

Now we have a new object, with a different reference:

```
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
k:REF#462−−−−−−−−−−−>| Object@REF#462 |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     | val: 1         |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
j:REF#123−−−−−−−−−−−>| Object@REF#123 |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     | val: 0         |
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−++
```

`{val: 1}` created a new object. Assigning that object's reference to `k` gave it a new value (the new object's reference). `j`'s value didn't change, because `k` and `j` have no link to each other.

Passing `k` into a function and receiving the value as `j` is just like doing `j = k` above: The *value* of `k` is passed into the function, and put in the parameter `j`. Going back to your original code:

```
var arr = [];
  var k;
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    k = {"val" : i};
    arr.push(
      (function(j) {
        return function() {
          console.log(j)
        };
      }(k))
    )
  }
console.log(arr[0](), arr[1](), arr[2]());
```

...each call to that IIFE in the middle creates an *execution context* with an *environment record* attached to it. An environment record is, conceptually, an object containing the variables and parameter values and such for the function call (you can't access this object in code, it's a concept in the specification, not necessarily a literal thing in the JavaScript engine). That environment record contains the `j` parameter. The IIFE creates a new function, which remembers a reference to the environment it was created in (using an internal slot called [[Environment]]), and returns that; the function gets pushed into the array.

So here's what memory looks like (again leaving out some unnecessary details) after the **first** loop:

```
                                                                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
k−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| Object@REF#2 |
                                                             |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       +−−−−−−−−−−+                                          |  | val: 0       |
arr−−−>|  Array   |                                          |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       +−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                  |
       | 0: REF#1 |−−−−>| Function@REF#1  |                  |
       | 1: REF#3 |−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | [[Environment]] |−>| Environment | |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                     |                       | j: REF#2    |−+
                     |                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>| Function@REF#3  |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        | [[Environment]] |−>| Environment |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                             | j: REF#4    |
                                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

After the second loop, you have this:

```
                                                                                    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
k−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| Object@REF#4 |
                                                                                 |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                                 |  | val: 1       |
                                                                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                             +−>| Object@REF#2 | |
                                                             |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                                                             |  | val: 0       | |
                                                             |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                                                             |                   |
                                                             |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+                                          |                   |
arr−−−>|  Array   |                                          |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   |                   |
       | 0: REF#1 |−−−>| Function@REF#1  |                   |                   |
       | 1: REF#3 |−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | [[Environment]] |−−>| Environment | |                   |
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
                    |                        | j: REF#2    |−+                   |
                    |                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                       |
                    +−>| Function@REF#3  |                                       |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |
                       | [[Environment]] |−−>| Environment |                     |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |
                                             | j: REF#4    |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after the third:

```
                                                                                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
k−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| Object@REF#6 |
                                                                                                        |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                                                        |  | val: 2       |
                                                                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                                    +−>| Object@REF#4 | |
                                                                                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                                                                                    |  | val: 1       | |
                                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                                                                +−>| Object@REF#2 | |                   |
                                                                |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
                                                                |  | val: 0       | |                   |
                                                                |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
                                                                |                   |                   |
                                                                |                   |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+                                             |                   |                   |
arr−−−>|  Array   |                                             |                   |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   |                   |                   |
       | 0: REF#1 |−−−−−−>| Function@REF#1  |                   |                   |                   |
       | 1: REF#3 |−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |                   |
       | 2: REF#5 |−−+ |  | [[Environment]] |−−>| Environment | |                   |                   |
       +−−−−−−−−−−+  | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |                   |
                     | |                        | j: REF#2    |−+                   |                   |
                     | |                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |                   |
                     | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                       |                   |
                     | +−>| Function@REF#3  |                                       |                   |
                     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |                   |
                     |    | [[Environment]] |−−>| Environment |                     |                   |
                     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |                   |
                     |                          | j: REF#4    |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   |
                     |                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                         |
                     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                                           |
                     +−−−>| Function@REF#5  |                                                           |
                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                         |
                          | [[Environment]] |−−>| Environment |                                         |
                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                         |
                                                | j: REF#6    |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: Thanks I got it now , the assignment is creating a new object everytime right?

Comment: doesn't `k = {val : i}` create a new object everytime? , as far as I understood, the object reference `k` remains in same place in memory and the address of object `{val: i}` is changing ?

Comment: @PruthviRaj: Yes, `k = {val : i}` does. Sorry, I thought you were talking about when you passed `k` into the function (which isn't assignment, but is very similar). Specifically, it's the `{val : i}` part that creates the object; the `=` part just assigns a reference to that object to `k`. I've extended the answer a fair bit to explain object references a bit more thoroughly, and show what you're building in memory in your loop.

Comment: wow neat , got it , thank you so much ! , ASCII arts are cool :)

Answer (score 1):

With `k = {"val" : i};` you are creating a new object and assigning it to `k`. Try `var k = {}` and `k.val = i` instead.

Comment: Ah now I get it, the equals is creating a new object everytime I see!

Answer (score -2):

You found a nice way to use closures. With primitives, such as number, javascript creates/copies the value into the new variable which is why you see 0,1,2.

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hrjLvgr9/

Notice how `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` all return 3 as you expected.

```
var arr = [];
var k;

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(function() {
        console.log(i)
    })
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        arr.push(function() {
            console.log(j)
        })
    })(i)
}

arr[0]()
arr[1]()
arr[2]()
arr[3]()
arr[4]()
arr[5]()
```